# Como proteger tokens de acesso em uma aplicação Web?

Tags: javascript, amazon-aws

Tenho uma aplicação na AWS e para acessa-lá preciso passar um *access token* e um SSID. Para acessar a aplicação da AWS eu tenho um *site*, porém as chaves estão escrita no código HTML, e qualquer um que acessar a fonte do site consegue ver as chaves.

Gostaria de saber como faço para esconder essas chaves.

Comment: Qual é o tipo de serviço da aws que você está utilizando?

Comment: qual o backend do seu site?

Comment: A tag "javascript" indica que você deve estar fazendo uma requisição AJAX para sua aplicação. Neste caso, não tem como esconder os dados. O que você pode é criar um endpoint no seu site para ser o intermediário. A página faz uma requisição sem token para o site e o servidor do site faz a requisição para a AWS. Assim os dados secretos permanecem no servidor apenas.